# How do I update my vscode extension's engine requirement from ^1.6.0 to ^1.8.0 without breaking my build?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I tried updating the vscode requirement in my extension by changing the `package.json` `engines/vscode` setting from `^1.6.0` to `^1.8.0` and now when I run `npm install` I get the following error:

```
node_modules/vscode-languageclient/lib/codeConverter.d.ts(1,23): error TS2497:
Module '"/Users/foo/vscode/clojure-debug/node_modules/vscode/vscode"' 
resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct.
```

I have tried removing the `node_modules` and `out` directories, but this makes no difference.

Is there some step I'm missing to update this?

Answer (score 6):

I think there's a little bit of confusion. Actually `engines/vscode` does not belong to node modules. So updating the `package.json` or making changes to your node modules won't do anything.

Instead, it's your version of your vscode. So to update it you have to update vscode itself.

If you have installed this with `apt`, you can just execute `sudo apt-get update` which will update the vscode. Currently, the [latest version in the vscode repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/releases) is `1.16.0`.

You can check your vscode version by executing:

```sh
code --version
```

and then set the engine version to your vscode version.

Hope this helps.