# @types/vscode ^x.xx greater than engines.vscode ^x.xx

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When I run [`vsce`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-vsce)

```sh
vsce publish
```

I get the following error:

```
@types/vscode ^1.62.0 greater than engines.vscode ^1.48.0

Consider upgrade engines.vscode or use an older @types/vscode version
```

I have the following dependencies in my `package.json`:

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/vscode": "^1.62.0",
    "vsce": "^2.5.0"
}
```

How do I update `engines.vscode`?

**Related**: [How do I update my vscode extension's engine requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41913284/1366033)

Answer (score 6):

According to publishing docs section on [Visual Studio Code compatibility](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension#visual-studio-code-compatibility)

> When authoring an extension, you will need to describe what is the extension's compatibility to Visual Studio Code itself. This can be done via the `engines.vscode` field inside `package.json`:

```json
{
  "engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.62.0"
  }
}
```